# Were battles in Lord of the Rings inspired by any historical events?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I wonder, has Tolkien ever mentioned if the great battles in *The Lord of the Rings* (Helm's Deep, Pelennor Fields) were inspired by any particular historical events, or has he ever stated otherwise?

I'm wondering especially about the cavalry charges, but the mentioning of any other moments of the battles will be also great.

Comment: I do know that Tolkien served in France in WWI, which was likely a source of the idea of the terror of mechanized war (bred Orcs, Grond, etc). As for specific battles, I'm not sure.

Comment: The battle of the Somme would be the main one, which Tolkien took part in, but any influence would not have been so direct.

Comment: According to Tolkien's foreward in later editions of LotR no events in any of the books are intended to reflect real world events and he hated that kind of allegory.

Comment: @IG_42 I see a difference between being modeled on something and representing it.

Comment: Yes. The The first European clash since 1815’s Battle of Waterloo, the Battle of Mons takes place in Mons, Belgium, with a British Expeditionary Force that numbers about 75,000 fighting an estimated 150,000 Germans in an attempt to hold the Mons-Conde Canal. The final of four “Battles of the Frontier” held in the first weeks of World War I, the British forces are overpowered when the German wizard unleashed a brigade of Urak-hai forcing them to retreat, handing the Germans a strategic victory. Some 1,600 British and 5,000 Germans casualties are reported, while no half-orcs were injured.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there's much evidence Tolkien was a history buff. He doesn't mention it in his letters, and I don't recall it being mentioned in Carpenter's (excellent) Tolkien biography.

Remember the inspiration behind LoTR and the rest of the legendarium was linguistic in nature: he wanted to create a world for his languages to live in. Historical accuracy was not really among his motives.

Comment: As @Plutor said though, there was inspiration from the destruction of Europe after the World Wars.

Comment: Tolkien does mention this in a roundabout way in a letter. Basically, he says his experience in the war(s) didn't affect the overall plot, but did affect the geography. EG Dead marshes were based on marshes in France. http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_226

Comment: Tolkien did not seem to have much interest in military tactics. I think it's significant that both the key battles in LOTR involve the defence of a fortress without much tactical cleverness on either side. In the books we mostly see either the viewpoint of a single individual within a battle, or the much bigger picture of the rise and fall of kingdoms (as in the appendices to LOTR).

Comment: I don't think one can know medieval literature and, more broadly, European literature inside and out like Tolkien did without being something of a history buff. As a linguist, I can attest that you have to know history by default to understand the relationships (both diachronic and synchronic) between and across languages.

Comment: Yes, but I think the influence of heroic songs like the *Beowulf* and the Eddas was much more direct and important to both plot and world-building than actual history (very unlike, say, George RR Martin).

Answer (score 15):

I don't think many can really say for certain what inspired the great battles of LOTR, but there are at least a number of parallels with real events.

The most notable being the similarities between the Battle of Pelennor Fields and the Siege of Vienna 1683.

At the time Vienna was viewed as the gateway to Europe, so when the Turks invaded, it was an essential objective. The European leaders recognized that if it were to fall, the Turkish army could advance deeper into the continent. The Attacking force was far greater and the defending garrison woefully undermanned. Sounds an awful lot like Minas Tirith.

However, a call for aid was sent out, and King Sobieski of Poland answered. Although that was also in response to an existing treaty. A relief force was also underway from the Holy Roman Empire.

When the relief force finally arrived, the German and Polish infantry set to work attacking the opposing force, which they did with great effectiveness. The Cavalry maneuvered into a better position to attack the greater Turkish force. Though the infantry were very effective, they were quickly becoming exhausted. Finally Sobieski emerged with a force of Cavalry numbering ~18,000 strong, with the Polish Hussars forming the vanguard. His charge routed the Turkish Army, and relieved the city. Incidentally his charge also has the honor of being the largest cavalry charge ever recorded.

These battles are hardly mirrors of one another, there are obvious differences. But I think it is easy to see how the battle of Vienna, it's importance to the Europe, and conclusion in a massive cavalry charge, could have inspired Tolkien's Battle of Pelennor Fields

I am not a very articulate individual, so my case may not be very convincing. But I encourage you to have a look at the Battle and determine whether or not you think there is any merit to the suggestion.

I read through both accounts and they strike me as very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think the similarities are even bigger between the Battle of Helm's Deep and the Siege of Vienna due to: (1) the Ottoman's plan to break the walls of Vienna was to plant several bombs underneath the walls -- which eventually they failed -- like in Helm's Deep, with the twist that there the orcs succeeded; (2) the "18,000 horsemen charged down the hills" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vienna#Battle) sounds a lot like the Gandalf-led cavalry charge of the relieving force in Helm's Deep. So really a lot of coincidences between fiction and reality.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments on the question. Tolkien had experience of the horrors of 20th century warfare, which may well have influenced his description of Saruman's strategies.

But for the most part, the great battles in *The Lord of the Rings* (Helm's Deep, Pelennor Fields, The Black Gate) seem to recall a simpler age when there was, at least occasionally, an opportunity for individual heroism to affect the outcome.

As a professor of Anglo-Saxon, Tolkien studied and translated many old English texts that described battles in the first millennium, so he would have been familiar with how they were described. It is reasonable to believe that he drew from these accounts when describing battles in *The Lord of the Rings*.

One possible source is the poem referred to as [The Battle of Malden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Maldon#The_poem_The_Battle_of_Maldon) which described the defeat of a Saxon army by Viking invaders. Tolkien studied the poem enough to be credited as assisting with the publication of a [modern translation](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Battle_of_Maldon).

> The Battle of Maldon is an edition of the Old English poem The Battle of Maldon. In his Preface, editor E.V. Gordon notes that J.R.R. Tolkien "read the proofs", made "corrections and contributions", and offered solutions "to many textual and philological problems".

The Tolkien Society has a document [Angle-Saxon - Part Two](http://www.tolkiensociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Anglo-Saxon-Part-2.pdf) that discusses (on pages 8 and 9) similarities between Tolkien's battles and the Battle of Malden. It also discusses (on pages 4-6) similarities between Tolkien's fiction and the Beowulf epic (of which Tolkien published a translation).

Answer (score 3):

The Battle of Pelennor Fields bears many strong resemblances to the Battle of the Catalaunian Plains. Although I do not know of any instances in which Tolkien himself confirmed this, he was likely familiar with this battle because of its importance to Roman history.

In this battle, the Romans fought the Hunnic Empire under Attila with the help of barbarian allies, called Foederati. The location of the battle is not known with certainty, but is somewhere in modern France. Attila invaded France, at that time called Gaul, in one of a series of conflicts with Rome.

The battle was won in large part because of Rome's barbarian allies, the largest part of whom were Visigoths. The Visigothic king, Theodoric I, died in the fighting.

The setting strongly parallels that of Middle Earth. A large established, but waning Roman empire (Gondor) is attacked by a foreign power (the Huns). Gondor prevails with the help of Rohan (the Visigoths), but at the cost of the life of Theoden (Theodoric).

There are other strong parallels between Rohan and the Visigoths. The Rohirrim are also nomadic peoples who have only recently settled in Rohan, having lived previously in the north of Middle Earth. Rohan was gifted to the Rohirrim from Gondor. Like the Rohirrim, the Visigoths had only recently settled in the Roman Empire and had migrated from North Central Europe. The Romans gave the Visigoths large grants of land in Gaul and expected military assistance in return.

Answer (score 0):

It is also interesting that Helm was an ancient Slavic name for the Balkans (Balkan is Turkish word for "mountain chain") which is mostly mountainous like Helms Deep. Can't help but think it was an inspiration for Tolkien. However unlike the battle at Helms Deep, when medieval Serbia called for aid, none of the European nations answered, so it was overwhelmed by a Turkish onslaught.

Comment: Do we have any reason, beyond blind supposition to believe that "Helm" in "Helm's Deep" had anything to do with the ancient Slavic name for the Balkans?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at history, I would have to go with Battle of Szigetvar and Battle for Vienna in the 16th and 17th century. I mean, look at these similarities from Battle at Szigetvar:

1. The European army was pretty much an alliance of different nationalities all trying to stop the Ottoman invasions.
2. The castle from which Europeans defended from the Ottoman hordes was divided into sections, similar as in the movie. Once one section fell, the defenders would withdraw and meet the invaders again.
3. Just like in the movie, once defeat was imminent, the Europeans decided to open the castle gates and charge at the enemy, preferring a heroic death over surrender.
4. The European army was vastly outnumbered - some sources quote over 100.000 Ottomans vs 2-3 thousand Croatian and Hungarian soldiers.
5. The walls were breached by explosives just like in the movie.

Big difference: The reinforcements never came and the Europeans left one last surprise for the Ottomans once everyone was killed - one of the wounded soldiers was left behind to light the explosives under the castle and blow himself up, killing another 3000 Ottomans once the battle was already lost. But that brings me to the Battle for Vienna where the reinforcements actually showed up! Polish Winged Hussars showed up over the ridge, pretty much like in the movie and saved the day by driving the Ottomans away.

Tolkien could have studied these two battles and combined them into one. This is even further hinted by the name "Helm's deep". Classical name for Balkan peninsula is "Heamus", "Hem", "Holm" which is the distortion of the Slavic word "Hum", which means a hill or a mountain.

If anyone else has any other suggestions I'm all ears, but I think the similarities here are astounding!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is interesting speculation, but the question was if Tolkien had *stated* anywhere what the battles were based on.  Do you have any evidence that Tolkien used these battles as a basis for his stories?

Comment: No, I don't have any such information unfortunately. I want to make it clear all of this is just speculation on my part. Still, you have to admit that similarities are pretty big.

Comment: That particular battle for Vienna (with the Polish Winged Hussars) was in 1683, which was the 17th Century. There _was_ a siege of Vienna in 1529; in that one, Suleiman's forces had to withdraw because of a plague outbreak.

Comment: Correct. Thank you for additional clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Bit late to the  party but the Helm's deep battle was inspired by both the Siege of Constantinople and the Siege of Vienna. The Elf's coming in was the Genoese who supported the Byzantines against the Ottomans. Similarly, the bombardment of the walls in the Battle of Pelennor Fields is very reminiscent of the Siege of Constantinople. The boats coming in with relief and not appearing at first. That was the promised ships from Venice which never came and many suspect if it did have troops and supplies could have swung the battle. The demo charges in the walls is how the Ottomans finally breached Constantinople. They used to dig tunnels under the walls, set explosives and blow them up. The Rohan charge at the end of Helms deep was the charge from the Siege of Vienna which wiped out the Ottomans.

Further bits I suspect were lifted was Gondor not heeding the call from Rohan. Which was the Catholics refusing to help Byzantine. If you look at the map placement, Mordor is at the bottom right, which on a European map of the time was where the Ottomans were based. Rhun, was where Hungary and Wallachia would be both of whom were defeated by the Ottomans and used to fight against Austria. Further evidence is Mirkwood which is eerily similar to the Wallachian woods. The grey mountains is Northern Hungarian Mountains which separated the PLC and Hungary.

Finally the Soldiers and leaders. First of all Saruman is Suleiman the magnificent the greatest ruler of the Ottomans. The Uruk-Hai was the Janissaries the most elite Ottoman troops who were taking from birth and trained to fight. The Rohan cav were the Polish Hussars. There are a lot of other ones with similar characteristics but i'd be here all day mentioning them. A lot of it was definitely inspired by the wars from 1450-1700.

Comment: Are you just drawing parallels between the battles here or do you have evidence that they were explicitly inspired by them?

Comment: you're going to really need to prove the assertions above, because you are essentially saying that, for example, Saruman is an allegorical depiction. Tolkien had this to say about people reading allegorical meaning into the work: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/411971-i-cordially-dislike-allegory-in-all-its-manifestations-and-always - TL;DR - no

Comment: Tolkien did not write that more than one Elf fought for Rohan.

Answer (score -3):

I thought the Battle of Pelennor Fields was based on the [Battle of Brunanburh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Brunanburh) in the 937 in England.

Comment: Why? What similarities are there?

Answer (score -4):

i somehow believe the battle of helms deep was inspired by the battle of szigetvar (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Szigetv%C3%A1r)

Comment: This post only vaguely addresses the question - tell us more about these two battles rather than simply posting a link with a one-liner about it.